# Find the maximum value of a for which there is a real number solution

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Equation 1: $x^2+y^2=1$
Equation 2: $x^2•y^2=a$

I am sure the normal way of finding a solution won't work for this question. Because when I simplified , I got $ a=x^2-x^4$.

Can you solve without graphing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are looking for real solutions of $x^2+y^2=1$, there exist a real $\theta$ such that $$x=\sin\theta,  y=\cos\theta.$$ Then $$x^2y^2=\sin^2\theta\cos^2\theta=\frac{1}{4}\sin^22\theta.$$ Hence $$0\le4a\le1.$$

Comment: How do you know what sin^2 2beta is

Comment: @user11355: $\sin 2\theta=2\sin\theta\cos\theta$ and it is given that $x^2y^2=a.$

Comment: Wouldn't a be any thing if 4a=4a